# Authentication routing with NextJS and AWS Amplify

Tags: typescript, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, next.js13

After spending days of research, I can't really figure out how to handle the authentication routing with NextJS and AWS Amplify. This is the first time I'm using NextJS and I want to disable the login/register page for logged in users and disable the dashboard for not logged in users.

I already tried to check if user is authenticated with the AUTH api inside a middleware file but this didn't work. Searching on Google also didn't help because I wastn't be able to find anything related to this.

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can successfully get a user info back from AWS Cognito (meaning you've configured your Amplify Cognito access properly), you need to use React [Context Provider](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) to have auth user information accessible for the whole app. Then, create some kinda route guard component and wrap your main app component in it.